# Не удаляется часть строки (string) в C#

Tags: c#, строки, циклы, textbox

Когда я копирую текст из TextBox(multiline) в строку, а потом пытаюсь из нее что-то удалить - со строкой НИЧЕГО не происходит. Вот часть кода:

```
public Find(string Ingr)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  string ingr = Ingr; 
  // Я понимаю, что и без этой строчки можно обойтись, но чтобы отбросить все сомнения, что проблема не в этом... 
  int firstIndex = 0;
  while (firstIndex < ingr.Length)
  {
    int lastIndex = ingr.IndexOf("\r");
    if (lastIndex < 0)
    {
      lastIndex = ingr.Length;
    }
    string subIngr = ingr.Substring(firstIndex, lastIndex);
    firstIndex = subIngr.Length;
    MessageBox.Show("" + subIngr);
    ingr.Remove(0, lastIndex);//Не работает ни эта команда
    //ingr.Replace(subIngr , ""); Ни эта
  }   
}
```

Допустим, пользователь вписал В TextBox:

"
Мука

Сахар

Молоко

Соль
"

Что делает моя программа...

Она берет все это дело, и присваивает в  "string ingr".

В 'ingr' появляется такая строка: "Мука\r\nСахар\r\nМолоко\r\nСоль".

После этого идет цикл 'while', и вот тут начинаются проблемы.

Сначала выводится MessageBox с надписью "Мука". Пока что правильно.

Наступает время команде "ingr.Remove(0, lastIndex);" или "ingr.Replace(subIngr , "");", но ничего не удаляется.

Цикл повторяется второй раз, теперь в MessageBox выводится "Са". И все, просто "Са". Ничего снова не удаляется, снова выводится "Са", и цикл бесконечен.

Я не знаю в чем проблема, просидел уже больше часа, перепробовал огромное количество разных вариантов, ничего не помогает...

Я только учу C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ingr = ingr.Remove(0, lastIndex);  // работает и эта команда
ingr = ingr.Replace(subIngr , ""); // и эта
```

Comment: Я знаю, что это рабочие команды, но в том то и проблема, что у меня они не работают...

Comment: @Nephilim Вы не видите различий между Вашим и моим вариантами?

Comment: Оу, все, я понял... 
Как же обидно, что столько времени потрачено из-за небольшой оплошности.
Благодарствую!

Comment: @Nephilim Не переживайте. Это нормальный процесс.

Comment: Было бы ещё неплохо, если бы вы подсказали: а что делать теперь?
Теперь, удалив слово "Мука", цикл зацикливается (простите за тавтологию), показывая пустой MessageBox.
Скорее всего, проблема в этой строке "int lastIndex = ingr.IndexOf("\r");", ведь при удалении - эта часть "\r" остаётся. Как можно решить эту проблему?
Я решил сделать в конце так: "ingr = ingr.Replace("\r", "");", но это удаляет ВСЕ эти знаки(перенос строки), так что ничего не получилось...

Comment: @Nephilim `ingr = ingr.Remove(0, lastIndex).Trim();`